# How to interactively expand a bang command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Shells like zsh and bash have *bang commands* which start with an exclamation mark and expand to items in the user's history.

To get the last argument of the the last command that was run, one can use `!$`, e.g.

```
$ echo one two three
$ echo !$ !$ !$
> three three three
```

In zsh, it is possible to expand these bang commands interactively:

```
touch foo bar
ls !$<TAB>
```

`!$` will be expanded to `foo` inline.

This is very useful because it often prevented me from mistakes: I press `tab` to expand and make sure I got it right and `C-/` to undo the expansion when I'm confident.

Is there a setting in bash to achieve interactive expansion of bang commands?

What about expansion of subshells and general variables for that matter (i.e. `echo $(uname)<TAB>` to `echo Linux` and `echo $SHELL<TAB>` to `echo /bin/bash`).

Comment: Your question presupposes that the reader understands what bang commands in zsh are.  You could probably reach a wider audience if you described the functionality that you are after.  I'm guessing M-. with a prefix argument is close to what you want, but I haven't googled.

Comment: http://structure.usc.edu/bash/bashref_8.html#SEC106 explains the available bindings.  M-C-e does general expansion so more or less what's in your second question. (Only one question per post in the future, please!)

Comment: I expanded a bit what I mean with bang command.

I assumed that the mechanism was the same for subshells, variables etc. that's why I included that second part of the question.

And you're right, thanks, the `shell-expand-line` was indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: Then yes, M-. does that.  Though I don't understand why the result is `foo` in your second example -- I would expect `bar`.

Comment: And M-^ does history expansion, although the history annotations are slightly different (... I think).

Comment: I'm not confident to post an answer based on this, but if you can scrape together an answer which satisfies yourself from these pointers, please be invited to answer the question yourself and mark the answer as accepted (after a cooling period, I think) so that this question no longer comes up as unanswered.

Comment: That's awesome.  http://structure.usc.edu/bash/bashref_8.html#SEC106 contains the information I needed. Googling often fails me for shell-related questions because of all the `!@#$%^&` and the varying terminology. So again, thanks @triplee for pointing me to the Command Line Editing manual page.

Comment: *if you can scrape together an answer which satisfies yourself from these pointers, please be invited to answer the question yourself* will do

Comment: I had this problem often and asked it in [How to search for dollar sign or exclamation mark?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289671/1983854). They told me http://symbolhound.com/ is the solution when you want to do such searches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few options you can use for history expansion. One is the `:p` modifier, which prints the expanded command instead of executing it.

```
$ echo foo
$ !!:p
echo foo
```

Another is to use the `histverify` option, which puts the result of history expansion in the shell buffer for editing instead of immediately executing it.

```
$ shopt -s histverify
$ echo foo
foo
$ !!
$ echo foo
```

If you're happy with the command, simply hit Enter again to execute it, as if you had just typed it.

By default, the Readline command `history-expand-line` is bound to `M-^` (`Alt-^` or `Esc-^`, depending on what your terminal emulator sends as the meta key), which expands any history expansions on the current command line.

There is also a general Readline command `shell-expand-line` (bound to `M-C-e` by default), which expands *everything* on the command line, just as the shell would after hitting Enter but just before actually executing it.

Comment: The `shell-expand-line` readline command was what I was looking for. `shopt -s histverify` is very useful as well, thanks. As @tripleee noted in the comments, the shortcut to get the last argument of the last command (i.e. `!$`) is `M-.` (`Alt+.` or `Esc-.`).

Comment: A `Ctrl-x` also expands the line (without execution).